# db4o leaves free objects after removing references from their container object. How to resolve it?

Tags: java, db4o

Does anybody know how to make db4o work in the following scenario? I tried cascadeOnUpdate() but failed.

```
class Class1 {
    int field;
}

class Class2 {
    Class1[] clsArray;
}

//I usually change objects of Class2 in this way
Class2 obj = getFromContainer();
obj.clsArray = null;
objectContainer.store(obj);
objectContainer.commit();
```

The problem is that db4o doesn't remove Class1 objects from the database, which doesn't meet my requirements. I tried cascadeOnUpdate() on Class2, however it didn't work either. Do I need to loop into Class2.clsArray and delete each object explicitly? or is there any simpler way someone can tech me.

Answer (score 0):

Your basically looking for some kind of 'Garbage Collection', where objects are deleted, when the are not referenced anymore.

db4o doesn't have this capability. You need to manually look through the array and delete the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't get to your question sooner, but hopefully I'm not too late to help.

In addition to `cascadeOnUpdate`, there's also `cascadeOnDelete`. For a reference about how to use it, [look here](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/configuration/objectclass/cascade_on_delete.htm), and [look here](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/configuration/objectfield_configuration.htm). There's an example of it like this:

```
EmbeddedConfiguration configuration = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();
configuration.common().objectClass(Person.class).objectField("father").cascadeOnDelete(true);
```

This will do what you want. You can assign it via specific fields (like above) or for an entire class:

```
configuration.common().objectClass(Person.class).cascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Here are the javadocs for it on [`ObjectClass`](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/api/com/db4o/config/ObjectClass.html#cascadeOnDelete%28boolean%29) and [`ObjectField`](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/api/com/db4o/config/ObjectField.html#cascadeOnDelete%28boolean%29).